# what modeling tool is being used to shape the meshes in the linked video demonstration

Tags: modeling

[image]

In this animation (from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=In-3pi28psk&feature=youtu.be)) the artist appears to be using a tool that lets him select a vertex, then move the vertex around in such a way that the other adjacent vertices also move, but not as much. The tool appears to create a circle that the user adjusts the size of in some manner.

What tool is he using in this video to shape the spheres?

Comment: Please try to explain your questions with words and images, not just links. See https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: I second @NicolaSap's comment specially as the video is 3mn long and not everyone has this much time to spent to decipher the issue at hand. Also please try to rephrase your title to describe your problem.

Comment: I've edited the question to hopefully clarify what I was asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>O</kbd>
 to turn on Proportional Edit in Edit Mode.  Use the mmb <kbd>[image]</kbd>
to scroll the influence range. (or via keyboard with <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd>)